# How can I extract object values from 3 nested json arrays by matched string object values from a separate array and then display it in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, match, key-value, map-function

I would like to match the "title" and "thumbnail" values from one json response array to the values in another response array and show them in an html list. Essentially I'm matching a multidimensional array by regEx to another array and then I'm trying to display the content in a list like the one at the bottom. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the 1st Array

```
jsonArray = [
  [{
    "position": "1",
    "title": "player 1",
    "thumbnail": "www.picuture.com/jpeg"
  }, {
    "position": "2",
    "title": "player 1",
    "thumbnail": "www.picuture2.com/jpeg"
  }],
  [{
    "position": "1",
    "title": "player 2",
    "thumbnail": "www.picuture.com/jpeg"
  }, {
    "position": "2",
    "title": "player 2",
    "thumbnail": "www.picuture2.com/jpeg"
  }],
  [{
    "position": "1",
    "title": "player 3",
    "thumbnail": "www.picuture1.com/jpeg"
  }, {
    "position": "2",
    "title": "player 3",
    "thumbnail": "www.picuture2.com/jpeg"
  }]
]
```

Below is the the second array it needs to match to

```
array2 = ["player1_details", "player2_details", "player3_details"]
```

I would like to have a html list with the title and image values from the jsonArray and the player details from array2.

```
example:
<ul>
  <li>player 1 </li><li>www.picuture1.com/jpeg" </li><li>player1_details </li>
  <li>player 2 </li><li>www.picuture2.com/jpeg" </li><li>player2_details </li>
  <li>player 3 </li><li>www.picuture3.com/jpeg" </li><li>player3_details </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: inorder to help you, you need to format your dataset properly, also your dataset has repeating values and the required information in your example does not exist in your provided dataset which makes it harder to provide an exact answer.

Comment: for example, what happens if theres a match for player3? do you want to take title thumbnail from object at position 0 or the one at position 1? or do you want to take both but then your example result only has one thumbnail. Its ambigious.

Comment: @WajeehHasan Ideally, it would be position 1 because that is the best thumbnail.

Comment: code does not understand what we think is best unless defined otherwise. so you need the object at position 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can do it like this to get player details from position 1 as discussed in comments, its one of the many ways, I have defined a class with required attributes and pushed class object into a list. After this you can use this list to show the details however you want

```
class reqInformation {
  constructor(title, thumbnail, details) {
    this.title = title;
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    this.details = details;
  }
}
p = new reqInformation("titletest","thumbnailtest","detailstest");
var finalList=[]
var loopCount = 0;
const itemPos = 1;



Object.keys(jsonArray).forEach(function(key) {
    var matchText = jsonArray[key][itemPos]['title'].replace("player ", "");
    if(array2[loopCount].includes(matchText)){
        var p = new reqInformation(
            jsonArray[key][itemPos]['title'],
            jsonArray[key][itemPos]['thumbnail'],
            array2[loopCount]);
    }
    finalList.push(p)
    loopCount++
});
console.log(finalList)
```

change `itemPos to 0` if you want object at position `0`